# trace32 using python: how to interpreat return data from function T32_ReadMemoryObj

Tags: embedded, python-3.8, trace32, lauterbach

Code is for reading 40 bytes of data from 32 bit address:

```
    size = 40
    addr = 0x02051000
    buffer = (c_uint8 * size)()
    buffer_handle = c_void_p()
    address_handle32 = c_void_p()
    self.t32_api.T32_RequestBufferObj(byref(buffer_handle), 0)
    self.t32_api.T32_RequestAddressObjA32(byref(address_handle32), addr)
    self.t32_api.T32_ReadMemoryObj(buffer, address_handle32, size)
    self.t32_api.T32_CopyDataFromBufferObj(buffer, size, buffer_handle)
    self.t32_api.T32_ReleaseBufferObj(byref(buffer_handle))
    return ''.join(map(str, buffer))
```

return data: 000000004000000003213746596610040000000000000000
but in trace 32 window it is showing
[image]

does API returning incorrect data? OR I have invalid code?

Comment: Hi Nirmi, are you sure you're reading the same memory? You don't set any access class. Can you add a picture of the whole Data.dump window?

Comment: @dev15 updated the exact value and picture

Comment: Which architecture are you using? The Remote API always uses byte addresses, whereas TRACE32 has some address multiplier depending on multiple factors.

Comment: Another guess: You could try to set the access class using `T32_SetAddressObjAccessString`, in your case something like this: `self.t32_api.T32_SetAddressObjAccessString(byref(address_handle32), b"MD")` after `self.t32_api.T32_RequestAddressObjA32(byref(address_handle32), addr)`.

Comment: The latest DVD R.2020.09 also has a Python module which can help you a lot, but make sure your license is valid: You can get it here: https://www.lauterbach.com/frames.html?download_trace32.html

Comment: @dev15, I tried adding T32_SetAddressObjAccessString as well, was getting same output.. after modifying T32_ReadMemoryObj properly and converting it each byte to hex got proper output. but what is the use of self.t32_api.T32_SetAddressObjAccessString(byref(address_handle32), b"MD"), when to use that api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is returning byte size in the integer format

from buffer taking each integer and converting into hex worked for me also one more code change:

```
    self.t32_api.T32_ReadMemoryObj(buffer_handle, address_handle32, size)
```

In the code earlier I passed buffer rather than buffer_handle.
After adding code to convert each byte into hex getting output: 00000000000000000400010000000002785634120000000000000000000000000000000000000000